# Microsoft Android build fails - Could not compile native assembly file

Tags: xamarin.android, maui, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, darwin

I've created an android project from template in visual studio for mac 2022 (checked supported abi: armebi-v7a)

When i build the projects I randomly get one or more of following errors:

```
Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error XA3006: Could not compile native assembly file: environment.arm64-v8a.ll

stderr | /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: error: /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: environment.arm64-v8a.ll:554:7: error: expected value token
stderr |                 i32 −1, ; apk_fd

(XA3006) (AndroidApp1)

Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1979, 3): [XA3006] Could not compile native assembly file: environment.x86.ll
stderr | /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: error: /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: environment.x86.ll:593:7: error: expected value token
stderr |                 i32 −1, ; apk_fd


Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1979, 3): [XA3006] Could not compile native assembly file: environment.armeabi-v7a.ll
stderr | /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: error: /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: environment.armeabi-v7a.ll:593:7: error: expected value token
stderr |                 i32 −1, ; apk_fd


Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1979, 3): [XA3006] Could not compile native assembly file: environment.x86_64.ll
stderr | /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: error: /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/33.0.26/tools/Darwin/binutils/bin/llc: environment.x86_64.ll:593:7: error: expected value token
stderr |                 i32 −1, ; apk_fd
```

What can be the problem ? It's working for TargetFramework .net6.0-android

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-android33.0.0</TargetFramework>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>21</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.AndroidApp1</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v11.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
  <AndroidEnableMultiDex>false</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
  <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My system:

```
.NET SDK:
Version:   7.0.202
Commit:    6c74320bc3

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Mac OS X
OS Version:  13.2
OS Platform: Darwin
RID:         osx.13-arm64
Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.202/

Host:
 Version:      7.0.4
 Architecture: arm64
 Commit:       0a396acafe

.NET SDKs installed:
 6.0.407 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
 7.0.202 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
 Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
 Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
 x64   [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64]
   registered at [/etc/dotnet/install_location_x64]

Environment variables:
Not set

global.json file:
Not found
```

EDIT: There is an encoding bug in xamarin for some languages. Description and workaround can be found here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7939

Comment: [Could not compile native assembly file: typemaps.arm64-v8a.s](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6974), this case could be helpful to you.

Comment: Already checked it but thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyone had this problem ?

Comment: I see this as well (.net7)

Comment: @Rhult I've created a issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7939

Comment: @Henrik - I am facing this problem for android project in Xamarin and MAUI both. How did you fix this ?

Comment: @R15 I've changed the locale as a workaround. But should've been fixed by now in a later version, if they've released it.

Comment: For me the issue appeared after switching form .net6 to .net7

Comment: @TomislavG - Same for me. Is there any fix ? I have raised it here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76554967/how-can-i-fix-compile-time-error-in-maui-could-not-compile-native-assembly-fil?noredirect=1#comment134984494_76554967

Comment: @Henrik - How can I change locale in Visual Studio MAUI project ?

Comment: @R15 you change it in your os.