# How can I fix compile time error in MAUI - Could not compile native assembly file

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

When I create new `MAUI` or `Xamarin.Forms` project in `Visual Studio 2022`, I get errors at the time of building project. I have tried various Visual Studio version (uninstall/reinstall) including latest VS Preview 2.  When I build project, I get errors only in Android project.

```
Rebuild started...
Restored C:\Users\user.name\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj (in 889 ms).
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MauiApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>MauiApp1 -> C:\Users\user.name\source\repos\MauiApp1\bin\Debug\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\MauiApp1.dll
1>MauiApp1 -> C:\Users\user.name\source\repos\MauiApp1\bin\Debug\net7.0-maccatalyst\maccatalyst-x64\MauiApp1.dll
1>MauiApp1 -> C:\Users\user.name\source\repos\MauiApp1\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\MauiApp1.dll
1>MauiApp1 -> C:\Users\user.name\source\repos\MauiApp1\bin\Debug\net7.0-android\MauiApp1.dll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.46\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1987,3): error XA3006: Could not compile native assembly file: typemaps.arm64-v8a.ll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.46\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1987,3): error XA3006: 
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.46\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1987,3): error XA3006: 
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.46\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1987,3): error XA3006:
1>Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Rebuild started at 4:16 PM and took 01:10.747 minutes ==========
```

In `MAUI` project when I target `.Net 6.0` **no errors**. When I use `.Net 7.0` or `.Net 8.0` I am facing this error.

Errors screenshot below. Sometimes I get one, two or three error. Those are random but all are related to arm architecture. There might be chances that given errors has nothing to do with actual error. This has been discussed on issue posted on GitHub

[image]

I have tried deleting obj and bin, cleaning project, reload and unload and opening VS as Admin, still facing same errors.

Even I have reported this issue [at github.com/dotnet/maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14531), [at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1222300/how-to-fix-could-not-compile-native-assembly-file) and [at developercommunity.visualstudio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-compile-native-assembly-file--/10336511) No solution. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Try delete solution’s hidden .vs folder. Try uninstall all versions of VS 2022, reboot, then install latest stable (not preview) again.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I have tried this, I have uninstalled VS and .net frameworks, installed new one, reboot and deleted .vs folder of new project. No use.

Comment: Try to rebuild ios first then android not all together.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas - MAUI don't have separate projects. In Xamarin project I had unchecked iOS checkbox so in that solution there is no iOS project. I am using windows machine.

Comment: Indeed there are not separate projects. But you can select Release/Generic Device and Build project (not build solution). That action will build only ios project. May be the results will help us to understand the issue.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas - see discussion at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14531. Add any further questions or suggestions there. (iOS isn't being asked for; problem seems to be an interaction with something in their IT setup of their team's pcs; devs have been suggesting things to try.)

Comment: Try reinstalling VS with all of the modules you need.

Comment: Do you have `Diagnostic` level logs?

Comment: @FreakyAli - You will find all the logs in given link of GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is got fixed. For more visit the below URL. This should be release along with next release of Xamarin and MAUI

*https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14531*